# Over the web and over the lan streaming with WAMP

Tags: streaming, wamp, lan

I want to set up a little website from which i can stream video/audio to my android phone. I'm  wondering will the WAMP server stream through LAN when both the phone and the pc are on the same network or will it still go through the web. I have low upload speed it's high enough to stream videos but i prefer the server to stream through lan when we're on the same network and over the web when we're not. So will the server do this by himself or should i look in another variant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will stream through the LAN.

There are no special things you need. The only thing is that the media won't actually stream. Whatever your media is will only play after completely downloading.